# Finding a call to a non-existent DLL function

Tags: qt, dll, libxml2

The Windows version of one of our products is bundled with several DLLs from Qt v597.  One of our customers is having trouble with an error box displaying that says an attempt to access the function xmlXPtrEval() in libxml2.dll (one of the DLLs from Qt) failed.  And indeed, the libxml2.dll that is bundled with the Qt v597 DLLs does not have a function by this name.

As far as I can tell, the errant call is dynamic (i.e., the attempt to find the function is done at run-time) and external to our application, as libxml2.dll is not a DLL upon which our application depends.

Is there a way I can find out what is making this errant call?  I'm assuming the call is being made by a DLL somewhere, Qt or otherwise, but which one?

Comment: No idea, but we may imagine that `xmlXPtrEval` is present in the binary, maybe in the wide characters form.

Comment: It seems that `libxml2.dll` was built *without* XPointer support, and an executable or another library like libxslt was linked against a version *with* XPointer enabled.

Answer (score 0):

may be install hook to catch function call? If it dynamic call, it can be executed from LoadLibrary and resolve. Also you can use injection if you can't change dll/app.